# Using input/output tests in Replit

Tags: java, testing, ide

A REPLIT specific question.

I have not found a way to make a passable Replit input/output test that includes input from the console and output to the console on the same line, but I am hoping it is possible.

Example of problematic code:

```
System.out.print("What should I do? ");
String whatNext = cmd.next();
System.out.println("I will do " + whatNext);
```

It seems I should not include the user input in the expected output, but unless I put a line break after my output, I can't find a way to make the test pass.

*** to clarify, my expected output does include the line break, but still won't pass, unless I change my program to not expect the input on a line with output. Hoping that makes sense.

I am hoping there is something I am missing.

Comment: the same line? as soon as you press enter the cursor moves down. this is not a repl.it bug,

Comment: @-Someone_who_likes_SE -- I am not thinking this is a bug, I am just asking if anyone knows if there is a way to describe the expected behavior that would allow the test to pass.